# How do you use a for loop to sort through a list from a text file and count the number of times it matches with a user inputted phrase?

Tags: python, list, file, input

The file WorldSeriesWinners.txt contains a chronological list of the World Series winning teams from 1903 through 2014. The first line in the file is the name of the team that won in 1903, and the last line is the name of the team that won in 2014. Note that the World Series was not played in 1904 or 1994.

Write a program that lets the user enter the name of a team and then displays the number of times that team has won the World Series since 1903.

Sample program runs are as follows:

---

> Enter team name: St. Louis Cardinals
>
> St. Louis Cardinals won 11 times

---

> Enter team name: Kansas City Royals
>
> Kansas City Royals won 1 times

---

> Enter team name: San Francisco Giants
>
> San Francisco Giants won 3 times

---

> Enter team name: Texas Rangers
>
> Texas Rangers won 0 times

---

Format the ouput of your program as shown in the sample program runs. Design your program so that it contains at least one function other than the main function. No code should appear outside functions.

Hint: You may want to read the contents of WorldSeriesWinners.txt into a list. When the user enters the name of a team, use a loop to step through the list, counting the number of times the selected team appears.

What I have so far:

```
def readfile():

f = open("WorldSeriesWinners.txt", "r")
lineList = f.readlines()
f.close()

List = []

for line in lineList:
    line = line.strip()
    List.append(line)


def main():

    name = input("Enter team name: ")
    readfile()
main()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to let the user ask about several teams in one run:

```
import collections

def main():
    with open('WorldSeriesWinners.txt') as f:
        count = collections.Counter(l.strip() for l in f)
    while True:
        team = raw_input('Enter team name (empty to exit):')
        if not team: break
        print('{} won {} times'.format(team, count[team]))
```

That's all of the (enhanced) program -- no need for multiple gyrations making lists!-)

Added: the OP makes some absolutely weird requests in comments -- (A) "do that in at least 2 functions" (why?! ah well, crazy pointless, but innocuous), (B) "simpler code, like a for loop instead" (it wouldn't of course be any simpler than the `l.strip() for l in f` genexp I'm using above -- indeed, more complicated -- so here I draw the line and simply refuse!), (C) "break at the end of each search of a name" (evil, as it steals functionality from the user, but ah well, that **was** the original spec, so I'm going to bend and accommodate **this** one).  So here's a variant satisfying A and C (but not B, **never** B!!!):

```
import collections

def count_wins():
    with open('WorldSeriesWinners.txt') as f:
        count = collections.Counter(l.strip() for l in f)
    return count

def main():
    count = count_wins()
    team = raw_input('Enter team name:')
    print('{} won {} times'.format(team, count[team]))
```

There -- two more lines, a bit less functionality.  How that's supposed to be an "improvement", well, this really I couldn't tell you!-)

Hint for seekers of (B): that requires adding 2 more statements, and a little study of https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter -- bah!

Comment: Cool, but how would you do that in at least 2 functions? And maybe simpler code, like a for loop instead? I'm kind of new to Python.

Comment: Also, it continues to run afterward. How would I write it to break at the end of each search of a name?

Comment: @RiverGinther This is already as simple as it gets. If you want to write your own counter it's the same as `with open('WorldSeriesWinners.txt') as f:` `count = {}` `for line in f: count[line.strip()] = count.get(line.strip(), 0) + 1` And this solution already lets you break when you enter an empty name.

Comment: @RiverGinther, splitting it in two functions is trivial, though absolutely pointless -- I'm going to edit the Q to show how.  Letting the user ask about just one team, when it's just as easy to let them ask about many (and just hit enter at the end to terminate), is **evil**: giving the user less, when you could easily give them more!  Still, I'm going to show that, too.  As for using a `for` loop rather than the `for`-line genexp passed to `Counter`, that's where I draw the line: making the code much more complicated, much less efficient, **for WHAT purpose**?!?!?!

Comment: Thanks. It's just to give me a more basic idea of what is going on. As I have used for loops before, but never a with statement. Just easier for someone that is starting out in python to understand better as for loops are a more basic thing. It is less efficient, but being able to understand it is a way better thing. If you could do that for me, that would be great! Sorry about that.

Comment: @RiverGinther, `with` is how you should almost always open files in modern Python -- nothing to do with `for` statements.  Where (at substantial cost in complexity and performance) a `for` statement _might_ conceivably be used, is (I called it request `B` in my edit) in lieu of the `for l in f` **clause** of the argument I'm passing to `collections.Counter` (which builds the counter the right way); you **could** build the counter as initially empty, then use a `for l in f:` **statement** instead of that more efficient **clause** to populate it more slowly and less efficiently.  But, **why**?!

Answer (score 0):

You want to read all the lines from a file and count the occurrences of a given team:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == team:
            count += 1
return count
```

Or:

```
return sum(1 for line in open(filename) if line.strip() == team)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def ans(name):
    return lineList.count('name')

with open(filename) as f:
    lineList=[line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    while 1:
        name = input("Enter team name: ")
        if not name:  # press Enter only to exit
           break        
        print('%s won %s times' %(name, ans(name))
```